# Can't get a servlet to behave differently depending on presence of a POST request parameter

Tags: html, post, servlets, junit

I have this in my servlet's doPost():

```
if(request.getParameter("mode").equals("html"))
    request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/Menu.jsp").forward(request, response);
else {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/success.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

I test for the execution of the first statement by having an HTML page with a form as follows:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Username:<br>
    <input type="text" name="user"><br>
    Password:<br>
    <input type="text" name="pass"><br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="html" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When I submit the form, the first statement (forwarding to Menu.jsp) executes correctly.
I test for the execution of the second statement by having a unit test (which I didn't write myself) that makes the post request directly, not through a form, as follows:

```
@Test
public void testLoginSuccess() {
    try {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        String jsonText = login(webClient, "bob3", "fred3");
        DocumentContext dc = JsonPath.parse(jsonText);
        Assert.assertEquals("success", dc.read("$['status']"));


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

The login method:

```
private String login(WebClient webClient, String username, String password)
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    WebRequest requestSettings = new WebRequest(new URL(URL_BASE+"Login"), HttpMethod.POST);
    requestSettings.setRequestParameters(new ArrayList());
    requestSettings.getRequestParameters().add(new NameValuePair("user", username));
    requestSettings.getRequestParameters().add(new NameValuePair("pass", password));

    Page page = webClient.getPage(requestSettings);
    String jsonText = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
    testLogger.log(Level.INFO, jsonText);
    return jsonText;
}
```

The test fails and gives me a FailingHttpStatusCodeException at this line inside the login method:

```
Page page = webClient.getPage(requestSettings);
```

Since I didn't write the test myself and don't fully understand its code, I can't tell why it's failing, but it's passing when I don't have the if-else in my servlet and, instead, always execute the else statement.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I was doing

```
request.getParameter("mode").equals("html")
```

where "request.getParameter("mode")" might return null if the parameter is not set then calling .equals on the null result.

Why didn't it give me a NullPointerException in the stack trace though??